# Copy a file to a folder, which has the same name as the original

Tags: ubuntu, file-copy

Hopefully, this should be an easy question for the experienced.

I have a list of folders (x1,x2, ..., xn) in a folder called "origin" (i.e. /origin/x1, /origin/x2 etc).

I want to take a particular file (im1.tif in my case) from **each** folder x1,x2, ..., xn in /origin and copy it to a folder in a destination folder called 'dest', which has the same name (i.e. /dest/x1, /dest/x2 etc).

Could someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find /origin -type f -name "*.tif" -exec bash -c \
'd="$(dirname $1)"; d=${d##*/}; fn=${1##*/}; 
[ -d "/dest/$d" ] && cp "$1" "/dest/$d/$fn"; ' _ {} \;
```